# How to set property of Dialog window ViewModel?

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, dependency-injection

I need to call Dialog window from other (my main) ViewModel and my WndEvent window has its own ViewModel with DI created by Ninject. So the code looks like:

```cs
WndEvent wndEvent = new WndEvent();
wndEvent.ShowDialog();

if (wndEvent.DialogResult.HasValue && wndEvent.DialogResult.Value)
{
    // Do stuff...
}

public class WndEventViewModel : BaseObservableObject
{
    private readonly IService _Service;
    public WndEventViewModel(IDictionaryService Service)
    {
        _Service = Service;
        EventsList = _Service.EventsGet(3);
    }
}
```

As you see EventGet method receiving int parameter. Can I somehow set this value before wndEvent.ShowDialog(); ?

I see other possibility:

```
WndEvent wndEvent = new WndEvent();
WndEventViewModel vm = new WndEventViewModel();
// fill here vm properties
wndEvent.DataContext = vm;
wndEvent.ShowDialog();
```

Or maybe some other way is more correct?

Comment: Are you using any MVVM framework of DI container? If yes,you can register everything inside it or use dialog service. If no, you last snippet is pretty correct

Comment: No, I don't use any mvvm framework.